# Changing Type From str to int for the IP Address

Tags: python, python-3.x

I trying to get all the IP addresses in the /24 range in Python 3.11. When running the program currently I am getting a ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '192.168.250.1'

I have tried type casting the startingip and endingip to an int but am still getting the error when iterating through.

```
import wmi
import socket
from datetime import datetime


# accesses the Windows WMI object to get the gateway and IP address
wmi_obj = wmi.WMI()
wmi_sql = "select IPAddress,DefaultIPGateway from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration where IPEnabled=TRUE"
wmi_out = wmi_obj.query(wmi_sql)


# gets the IP address of the machine running the script (for logging)
# Omits APIPA addresses
def is_valid_ip(ip):
    parts = ip.split(".")
    if len(parts) == 4 and parts[0] == "169" and parts[1] == "254":
        return False
    return True


# gets the gateway that to be able to connect to the sonicwall
def get_gateway():
    for dev in wmi_out:
        # check if default gateway is not empty
        if dev is not None and hasattr(dev, "DefaultIPGateway"):
            gateway_list = dev.DefaultIPGateway
            if gateway_list and len(gateway_list) > 0:
                # check if any gateway in the list is not empty
                non_empty_gateways = [gateway for gateway in gateway_list if gateway]
                if non_empty_gateways:
                    return gateway_list[0]


def starting_ip(gateway):
    ip = gateway.split(".")
    ip[3] = "1"
    return ".".join(ip)


def ending_ip(gateway):
    ip = gateway.split(".")
    ip[3] = "254"
    return ".".join(ip)


def scan(gateway):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(1)
    result = sock.connect_ex((gateway, 135))
    if result == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False


gateway = get_gateway()

startingip = starting_ip(gateway)
endingip = ending_ip(gateway)
startingip_int = startingip


for ip in range(int(startingip), int(endingip)):
    print(ip)
```

Comment: Why are you using strings and ints at all? Python has a rich abstraction over IP addresses as [part of the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html). Don't use primitives when richer data types are available.

Comment: ...more specifically: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#conversion-to-strings-and-integers

Comment: @ForceBru I saw that before but wasn't sure why when printing the IP address as an int it would display a number that wasn't the IP address. The documentation you linked shows this also.

Comment: @pandapunk94, an IP address is just a number: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address, so the number `int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(...))` returns _is_ the IP address.

Comment: @ForceBru Thank you! This does what I want. Sucks that I had this solution a couple of hours ago and passed over it because I didn't think it was right. lol